# Add a link to the Help Center to the logged-out view

Tags: feature-request, help-center, top-bar

As an existing user, I can get help (such as "what's on topic here? oh yeah"):

> [image]

But as a nonexistent user, I can't get help (such as "what's on topic here? uhhhhhh...."):

> [image]

Let's help out the nonexistent users a bit, shall we? It'd help to throw a Help Center link into the top bar?

Us experienced users know to just navigate to `/help`, but most users probably won't try that.

Comment: What, you mean the help link hidden at the bottom of the about page accessed through the `Tour` link isn't enough?! (+1)

Comment: Why does your navbar say *Badgers*...?

Comment: @Emrakul Reminded me of [The Badger Song](http://weebls-stuff.com/songs/badgers/) (WARNING blasts out sound upon pageload).

Comment: @michaelb958 Actually, this one comes from the good friends at RPG.SE. That song is now something I'm very familiar with /grin

Comment: I think the reasoning behind this is that the help center is mainly for people who are already using the site, not for random visitors. I tend to agree with this reasoning.

Comment: @Sha What about the user who's not sure if their question is on topic? Do they need to create an account?

Comment: @Emrakul well, they'll click the big "Tell me more" button leading them to the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and in there it's explained pretty well under "Get answers to practical, detailed questions". Good enough in my opinion. If still not satisfied, the user can scroll down until he sees the "Looking for more in-depth information on the site?" and "Visit the Help Center" button leading to the help center sanctuary. :)

Comment: @Sha While I agree that the information is there, very few users are likely to click the "Tell me more" button; I doubt it's as effective as we would like it to be.

Comment: @Emrakul question is: suppose we add "help". How many users will actually click it? Same way very few are likely to click "Tell me more", good chance very few will also click "help".

Comment: @Sha I disagree; I think the "Tell me more" button looks like it has a flood of poor information behind it (from the outside; I know it doesn't), whereas a "help" might be useful. Just what I see, though. May not be true from the perspective of an outside user.